# How to add custom info to a TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, customize

My document follows a standard sectioning:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{The technical details}
\subsection{The frame}
\subsubsection{Leveling system}%Model A, Model B
\subsubsection{The Drawbar}
\subsubsection{Underside}

\subsection{The trunk}
\subsubsection{Style}
\subsubsection{The boxes}%Model A
\subsubsection{The doors-table}% Model B
\end{document}
```

From this sectioning, I need to make a table like this:[image: a TOC with extra columns]
Building this kind of tabular by hand is error-prone.

I would like to be able to include the info at the \subsection and \subsubsection levels like this:

```
...
\usepackage{amssymb}
...
\section{The technical details}
\modelsubsection{The frame}{Frame}
\modelsubsubsection{Leveling system}{Leveling}{\checkmark}{\checkmark}
\modelsubsubsection{The Drawbar}{Drawbar}{-}{-}
\modelsubsubsection{Underside}{Underside}{-}{-}    
...
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Might be possible using one of the parallel-packages: https://ctan.org/topic/parallel . I'd try to put the TOC into col.1; perhaps you can create your choices as one single column2.

Comment: I'll have a look to that package. I wonder about the "one single column2" because, one day, I'll have a third "Model C" and later another "Model D"... Thx

Comment: If so, you’ll adjust col2 as needed. These packages were designed, e.g. to list different languages in parallel. So they provide some sort of synchronization, when you need it. // Think of layouting the right column as a separate text or document, which you simply plug-in into a parallel column.

Comment: something like `\subsubsection[{Leveling\protect\marginpar{checkmark,checkmark}}]{Leveling system}` would add text to the toc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nice! Thx. Any idea how I could isolate the sub and subsub parts of the TOC for my table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest package `etoc` which allows a lot of customisation of the toc. Of course, you should style all the levels as you wish. Here a proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoc}

\title{...}


\newcommand{\modelA}{}
\newcommand{\modelB}{}

\newcommand{\modelsubsubsection}[4]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\modelA{#3}\protect\renewcommand\protect\modelA{#4}}\subsubsection[#2]{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begingroup\parindent 0pt \parfillskip 0pt \leftskip 0cm \rightskip 0cm
\etocsettocdepth{4}
\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}{}{}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}{\textbf{\etocname}\par}{}
\etocsetstyle {subsubsection}
              {}
              {}
              {\etocnumber.~\etocname\hfill\etocpage\quad\makebox[3em]{\modelA\quad\modelA}\par}
              {}              
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{The technical details}
\subsection[Frame]{The frame}
\modelsubsubsection{Leveling system}{Leveling}{\checkmark}{\checkmark}
\modelsubsubsection{The Drawbar}{Drawbar}{-}{-}
\modelsubsubsection{Underside}{Underside}{-}{-} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lacobus1983 Great. Thx for the proof of concept. I just need to remove the section numbering (I guess through the \etocnumber) and to add the colon titles ("Model A", "Model B"). I'll read the doc of the package. Thx again for your time and your careful attention!

Comment: +1 to @Iacobus1983...

Answer (score 6):

This is only a comment to [@Iacobus1983 answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689610/293669) which started as a comment but got too long.  There is a typo there that `\ModelA` is used twice in place of `\ModelA` and `\ModelB`.  The code proposed here hijacks the section style to draw the decoration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoc}

\title{...}


\newcommand{\modelA}{}
\newcommand{\modelB}{}

\newcommand{\modelsubsubsection}[4]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\modelA{\makebox[2em]{#3}}\protect\renewcommand\protect\modelB{\makebox[2em]{#4}}}\subsubsection[#2]{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begingroup\parindent 0pt \parfillskip 0pt \leftskip 0cm \rightskip 0cm
\etocsettocdepth{4}
% The code here could be simplified (second \rlap and \hspace unneeded) but
% is presented this way to allow easy extension to Model C, Model D etc...
\etocsetstyle{section}{\noindent\hfill\quad\makebox[4em][l]{\rlap{\rotatebox{45}{Model
    A}}\hspace{2em}\rlap{\rotatebox{45}{Model B}}\hspace{2em}}\par}{}{}{}

\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}{\textbf{\etocname}\par}{}

\etocsetstyle {subsubsection}
              {}
              {}
              {~~~~\etocname\hfill\etocpage\quad\modelA\modelB\par}
              {}              
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{The technical details}
\subsection[Frame]{The frame}
\modelsubsubsection{Leveling system}{Leveling}{\checkmark}{\checkmark}
\modelsubsubsection{The Drawbar}{Drawbar}{-}{\checkmark}
\modelsubsubsection{Underside}{Underside}{\checkmark}{-} 
\modelsubsubsection{No marks}{No marks}{-}{-} 
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with extra custom info]

Please upvote [@Iacobus1983 answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689610/293669) and only on second thoughts consider upvoting mine which is only an extension.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. Your (perfect) code will save me hours. Thank you for your time. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @user691586 thanks for mentioning me and for sharing!

Comment: @Iacobus1983 sorry for misspelling your alias in my answer! (I have fixed it now)

Comment: @JosephMarie glad it helps!